# Tcl Tk text widget tracking current line column position when you only use keys...not the mouse

Tags: text, widget, tcl, cursor, tk-toolkit

The problem is my ignorance.
The left mouse button works fine Re giving me the right line and column Re the current cursor position

But I want to avoid the mouse completely and just use keys. Unfortunately I don't get anything like the right line column no matter what I do. Can some one explain please. I want to do things only with the keys and know where that cursor is at every stage. Thanks

```
bind .t <Button-1> {? "wm title . [%W index @%x,%y]"}
```

and it works like a dream but that's with the mouse that I want to avoid

and this with the keys that doesn't give me 6.0 despite the cursor moving there like a goodun.

```
.t  mark set insert 6.0 
.t insert 6.0 ""
bind .t <KP_Insert>     {wm title . [%W index @%x,%y]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the position of the `insert` mark (because that is where the insertion caret is)... *after* the class bindings have acted.

The first thing to try is to put a binding on `<Key>` (i.e., any key press) that postpones reading the position so the class bindings have a chance to act. You do it this way because the class bindings run after your instance bindings, and some of them may do `break` to prevent global bindings from doing the wrong thing.

```
bind .t <Key> {after idle {wm title . [%W index insert]}}
```

The `after idle` is perfect for this; that schedules the change for the same time that the actual redraw of the widget happens.

---

In reality, I'd use helper procedures here:

```
proc retitleAfterKey {txt} {
    if {[winfo exists $txt]} {
        set top [window toplevel $txt]
        wm title $top [$txt index insert]
    }
}

bind .t <Key> {after idle {retitleAfterKey %W}}
```

Comment: I find my self looking for answers and yours are very often the ones that help me. Again, thank you very much and a very happy rest of the Easter to you.